# How can I put a back button in navtab in a scrollableview with Titanium Alloy?

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

I need to put a back button in the navtab in a scrollableview and I don't know how. Thanks.

Comment: You want the window to close and have back button as iOS does?

Comment: Yes, that is just I want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use titanium navigation window

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.NavigationWindow

Thanks